# Windows 7: Folder Size Restrictions - Multi-folder symlinking

Tags: python, windows, filesystems, symlink, directory

A bit of an odd question, kind of two in one honesty; Currently looking to do this in Windows 7.
I have Folder A and Folder B, both with different files in them. First thing I would like to do is set a restriction so that no more then 5GBs worth of files can be saved in each folder.

Second this, is what I’d like to do is in a sense “symlink” the two folders together in to Folder C. So that all the files contents in folders A and B will display within Folder C.

I work best in Python, but willing to optimize to any language to get something like this done. I’m looking for opinions on the best way to approach something like this. Any help or advice is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Take a look at [this article](http://www.gbuffer.net/archives/343) about setting a quota on folders.

Comment: [Windows 7 libraries](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/features/libraries) provide a single view over multiple directories, though this is a shell feature, not a file-system feature.  The old [DOS APPEND command](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_MS-DOS_commands#APPEND) did something similar, but that's not much use unless you want to use Windows 9x.